# Machine Public IP

Tags: linux, ip

I already had a small code that does this but it seems like it was not doing what i really needed it to do.

I was using the following commands to get Public IP.

> dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
>
> curl ipinfo.io/ip

Sadly, these give me the Public IP that the rest of the world can see my machines/servers as. In reality, they all have different public ip addresses. Sadly, i have no idea how i can get it from Linux terminal.

Right now i have:

> redmine   XXX.XXX.XXX.238
>   mail  XXX.XXX.XXX.234
>   git   XXX.XXX.XXX.237

But when i use the commands i mentioned below, i get

> XXX.XXX.XXX.227

This is also the public IP that everyone sees us as, thats why these commands don't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the XXX.XXX.XXX part of redmine, mail and git the same? How about the one for the one ending in 227?

Comment: Yes, the XXX.XXX.XXX is the same, just the ending is different for them all.

Comment: your firewall is probably NATing your machine

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read about NATs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). You did not share the entire IP, so I can only suspect, but I believe the IPs for redmine, mail and git are private IPs (only inside your network), while the one ending in 227 is the public one for all 3 services.

Does the following command return the same .227 IP address from both redmine, mail and git servers (if you SSH into them)? If so, then you are behind nat and that is the public IP for all 3 machines.

```
curl v4.ifconfig.co
```

How about the v6 IP? Is it the same for all 3?

```
curl v6.ifconfig.co
```

Comment: yes, iv i do ur first command, its the same for them all.

Comment: Basically your network is behind a NAT. You have a single public facing IP for the entire network and that IP is the one that the curl command returns.